# Scratching my head can kill me

Tags: riddle

I am thin and frail.
Scratching my head can kill me.
When abused, I can also kill you.
Usually, I'm helpful.

Comment: Usually riddles rhyme.

Comment: Sounds kind of threatening also.

Comment: I was gonna say "a cat", but cats are never helpful.

Comment: @TylerDurden Why must it rhyme? There are plenty of riddles that don't. Even more so when translating riddles from a different language.

Comment: All I know is what I read in The Hobbit.

Comment: @istrasci Scratching a cat's head doesn't kill it.

Comment: @FollowMyProposals:  Well, kills it with relaxation.

Comment: @istrasci OK then.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Answer:

> You are a match -

*My body is thin and frail:*

> Matches are thin. Wooden matches are easy to snap, paper matches are even easier to bend.

*Scratching my head can kill me:*

> When a match is scratched (on the striker for a safety match or on any dry frictional surface for an old-fashioned light-anywhere match) it burns, after which it is 'dead' - i.e can't be lit again.

*When abused, I can also kill you:*

> We are all taught as children how it is dangerous "to play with matches". Fires can kill...

*Usually, I'm helpful:*

> Of course - helpful for lighting a useful fire, or a cancer stick etc...

Answer (score 27):

Will this also qualify as an answer?

> Pencil

Scratching head can kill me

> Sharpening a pencil rescues it length and it becomes useless after a while i.e. dead ... Also a dull pencil is of no use till sharpened again

Abuse

> Poking the pencil in wrong place can lead to death

Helpful

> Used to express thoughts and ideas ... Transfer knowledge

Comment: Good lateral thinking :) Could do with some beefing out like the other answer, though.

Comment: @dewi added explanation ... @ others I know you are protective of the community, but please don't go down voting because you don't agree ...at least leave a comment to why you down vote

Comment: Strongly agree - commentless downvoting is poor form.

Comment: Very creative answer, and it does also seem to meet the riddle's requirements.  However, death by pencil seems to be more unlikely, so I wouldn't say it is the best answer, but I'm impressed regardless.  Your subject seems to be a fine idea for a riddle. +1  Regarding downvotes, I have sympathy.  You should see the the downvotes on a couple of my weaker riddles.

Comment: "death by pencil seems to be more unlikely" - I guess you didn't see that scene in The Dark Knight where the Joker makes a pencil disappear through a henchmans eye and into his brain ... :)

Comment: One could also argue that a person in power could abuse their power using a pencil and call for the execution of innocents/you?

Comment: The "abuse" answer could be ingesting lead, even though pencil leads aren't really made of lead any more...

Answer (score 24):

The real answer is glaringly obvious:

> condom

I am thin and frail.

> Ever used a cheap one?

Scratching my head can kill me.

> How do you think I got my kid?

When abused, I can also kill you.

> How do you think I got my syphilis?

Usually, I'm helpful.

> Usually...

Comment: This has to be the correct answer :)

Comment: Yes, this is a clever answer too.  lol

Answer (score 16):

This is my first guess at the answer

> Mercury Thermometer

*My body is thin and frail:*

> Glass body is very fragile to being broken from children

*Scratching my head can kill me:*

> Has a head that if scrated would break the glass making it no longer work properly

*When abused, I can also kill you:*

> Mercury poisoning!

*Usually, I'm helpful:*

> Taking temperature for everyone

Let me know what you think

Comment: That is a good reasoning. I like it! Not the best one, but it is a good answer! Keep up the nice work!

Answer (score 10):

My first thought was that you are a:

> Video tape

*My body is thin and frail:*

> The tape is very thin.

*Scratching my head can kill me:*

> If you scratch the head in the video player, it can rip the tape.

*When abused, I can also kill you:*

> You could probably pull the tape out and strangle yourself with it if you were really unlucky...

*Usually, I'm helpful:*

> At keeping kids entertained.

I admit that my answer works best for the head-scratching part, the rest of it is a little bit stretched...

Comment: Although I don't think this is *the* answer, +1 for a creative solution

Comment: @Jon - lol, clearly not *the* answer - a different one has been accepted already!

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> A needle

Because-

> Sharp tip, if scratched becomes blunt and useless,
>   Thin too
>   It can kill
>   It is helpful

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was

> A spider

I am thin and frail.

> Most certainly.

Scratching my head can kill me.

> From what I gather, if you stroke a spider's head, they "go bald". I presume enough of this can kill them.

When abused, I can also kill you.

> Spiders can be deadly.

Usually, I'm helpful.

> House spiders are especially helpful at killing house flies.

Comment: I'm not sure about the thin and frail part.